# Bad slice index Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Here is the definition of tensor in tensorflow:

```
word_weight   = tf.get_variable("word_weight", [word_num])
x_index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sentence_length, 1])
```

When I try :
 `word_weight[0]` or `word_weight[1]` or others, it works, I can get the result. But when I try `word_weight[x_index[0,0,0]]`,I get error:

```
TypeError: Bad slice index Tensor("modle/RNN/Squeeze_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow's implementation of the subscript operator (`__getitem__`) on Tensors is a syntax sugar for the `tf.slice` function. The subscript operator implementation supports Python integers, lists, tuples, and `slice` as the type for the subscript. As you have discovered, a `Tensor` itself is not supported as a subscript. However, you can use the `tf.slice` function directly for your purposes :

```
word_num = 100
sentence_length = 10
word_weight   = tf.get_variable("word_weight", [word_num])
x_index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sentence_length, 1])  
ind = x_index[0, 0, 0:1]
_ = tf.slice(word_weight, ind, [1])
```

Comment: Why slice should be x_index[0, 0, 0:1] but not x_index[0, 0, 0]?

Comment: `x_index[0, 0, 0]` returns a scalar (shape `()`), whereas `x_index[0, 0, 0:1]` returns a tensor (shape `(1,)`). `tf.slice` requires tensors for it's arguments.